# If "setNavigationBarHidden:YES", then how to come back to previous controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I don't want to let the navigation controller show its navigation bar in the whole project.

---

Now there are three view controllers

- (1) Login view controller
- (2) Sign up view controller
- (3) Home view controller.

---

I just hope to use action(which can be triggered by any kind of event, i.e. drag gesture, not necessary the pressing button) to switch between these view controllers. But I found once I get to the "signup view controllers", I can not go back to the login view controller, since there is no "BACK" navigation bar.

---

Questions:

- How "PUSH" in one view controller, then "POP" in the other view controller?
- Or there is some different way to solve this problem?

---

Thank you so much, any suggestion is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmaticaly go backward in a navigation controller's navigation stack, call this method:

```
[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When and where you call this is up to how you want your app to flow.  Essentially, the default navigation controller calls this automatically when the navbar's back button is pressed.  But if you hide the navbar and still need to pop back, you can call this method to pop back.

As for pushing forward, it's simply a matter of creating a Push segue on the storyboard, giving it a name, and then in your code, call this method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_YOUR_SEGUE_ID" sender:self];
```

---

On the question of your app, what probably makes most sense is for the login view be a view by itself.  It should contain a modal segue to a sign up view for new users as well as a modal segue to the home view controller (which may or may not need to be embedded in a navigation controller).

Performing a modal segue works exactly the same as a push segue (if you're using storyboards.  Hook up the segue, choose a modal segue, then call the `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method in your code when you need the segue to occur.

Dismissing a modal view is slightly different, but still quite simple.  It goes like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)  But I need to do "push" in the login view controller, and had to do "pop" in the sign up view controller, but how to do "push" and "pop" in the different ".m"file?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer. The segue, it really works. Thank you so much : )

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly check to do with an 'if' statement...

```
if (self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden == NO) {
//YOUR ACTION
}
```

Hope that helps!